# Can I generate a clock pulse by using just one SPST switch?

Tags: power-electronics, optoelectronics

Why can't I get output for IC 7490 by just toggling the SPST switch (to generate a CLOCK pulse )?

Comment: Have you used a pull-up resistor and connected one side of the switch to ground?

Comment: Due to contact bouncing it will be difficult to generate *exactly one* clock pulse.

Comment: No, I have not  used a resistor connected with switch.

Comment: @Wouter van Ooijen -can you explain what do you mean by contact bouncing.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce

Answer (score 2):

TTL inputs default high, and 7490's clock on low-going edges, so all you have to do to clock one is to connect one side of the toggle switch to the 7490's clock pin and the other end to ground.  Then, every time you toggle the switch from OPEN to CLOSED, you'll clock the 7490.

The count will be erratic, however, because the moving contact in the switch will bounce on the fixed contact and clock the 7490 many times until it finally comes to rest.  To clear up that problem you'll need to debounce the switch, which is a whole 'nother question.

Also, good practice dictates that if you're driving it with a switch you should connect about 4.7k from the clock pin to Vcc for bipolar TTL, which is what a 7490 is.